# Add certain nested attributes on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form with nested attributes. My nested attributes all work fine.

But, i want to have a selection of those attributes available for the user to check (true/false) to include in the creation of the form. The below code isn't working for me, unsure of what i'm missing.

**Form**

```
<%= form_with(model: staff, local: true) do |f| %>    
  <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order('last_name'), :id, :full_name %>
  <%= f.collection_select :department_id, Department.all, :id, :name %>

  <%= f.check_box :sale_checkbox, {}, true, false %><%= f.label "Sales" %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :management_checkbox, {}, true, false %><%= f.label "Management" %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :summary_checkbox, {}, true, false %><%= f.label "Summary" %>
<% end %>
```

So with the above code, sometimes sales isn't applicable, so a user would deselect it and therefore it wouldn't be included in the form creation.

**Controller**

```
def create
 @staff = Staff.new(staff_params)
  if params[:staff][:sale_checkbox] == true
    @staff.sales.build
  end
  if params[:staff][:management_checkbox] == true
    @staff.managements.build
  end
  if params[:staff][:summary_checkbox] == true
    @staff.summaries.build
  end
end

def staff_params
  params.require(:staff).permit(:sale_checkbox, :management_checkbox, :summary_checkbox)
end
```

**Model**

```
class Staff < ApplicationRecord
 attr_accessor :sale_checkbox
 attr_accessor :management_checkbox
 attr_accessor :summary_checkbox
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the server log, you will see that the `params` appear under `staff` hash, so your code doesn't work. Moreover you should change `true`  to `"true"` and `build` to `create`. The below code should work

```
def create
  @staff = Staff.new(staff_params)
  if params[:staff][:sale_checkbox] == "true"
    @staff.sales.create
  end
  if params[:staff][:management_checkbox] == "true"
    @staff.managements.create
  end
  if params[:staff][:summary_checkbox] == "true"
    @staff.summaries.create
  end
end
```

Comment: Great thanks @pavan. But now in my log i'm seeing **Unpermitted parameter: :sale_checkbox** sale_checkbox doesn't exist in my db, so I don't have it in my attributes, but I though it didn't need to be just to pass some params in.

Comment: @DollarChills Then you can declare it as a virtual attribute by including `attr_accessor :sale_checkbox` in `Staff` model and whitelist that attribute in the `staff_params`

Comment: Thanks @pavan. I have added the required attr_accessor to my model and staff_params (updated code above). The log does recognise the fields now, but the nested forms still show up if false.

Comment: @DollarChills What do you mean by *the nested forms still show up if false*?

Comment: Sorry I meant that the if params[:staff][:summary_checkbox] == true isn't being recognised. Either if the checkbox values are True or False it doesn't create the part of the nested form.

Comment: @DollarChills `build` doesn't create any records. Try changing it to `create`

Comment: Still the same issue. Doing my head in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181721/discussion-between-pavan-and-dollarchills).